# Cordova app after signing the apk need CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cors

I am working on a cordova app and using few ajax calls.
On local(browser) doesnt work beacuse of CORS. But in apk-debug is ok, I can call the urls.

When I sign the APK getting CORS errors again.

url is CHI script, added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` too

I use whitelist plugin with this settings in config

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

meta from index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
```

What is changing when I sign the apk?

Tested with different content-security-policy - nothing works

Ajax always returns `readystate 0` in signed app, in browser or in debug apk 100% works even with GET or POST.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, the problem is actually on the web server you are calling your requests to. I solved it by adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the .htaccess file.

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: I know that, but I dont understand why on debug app works, so is not asking for cors and in signed apk not. What's the difference?

Comment: added that and still same thing. In signed apk not working. In browser works

Comment: Are you using HTTPS or HTTP?

Comment: https - i think it's from Content-Security-Policy but can't find the correct one

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add the exact error message and perhaps the relevant code from your Cordova config file?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

**Let's Encrypt SSL certficate not trusted by Android**

Looks like Google doesn't like cheap things :)